# Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail Don't know what quota I am reaching or how?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, quota

[image: Error message screenshot]

This is likely the section of code with the error leading to the quota being reached:

```
function getGmail() {
  const query = "in:inbox subject:New Ticket Purchased For NOT label:done NOT label:FAILED";
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var l1 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("done");
  if (!l1) l1 = GmailApp.createLabel("done");
  var l2 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FAILED");
  if (!l2) l2 = GmailApp.createLabel("FAILED");
  var messages = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    messages.push([
      threads[i].getMessages()[0].getPlainBody(),
      threads[i].getMessages()[0].getDate(),
      threads[i]
    ]);
  }
  return [messages, l1, l2];
}
```

Is the way we are searching the inbox here problematic? Does anyone know of a way to reset the quota? What quota might we be reaching?

Comment: See this link [Google Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Answer (score 0):

There is no a specific problem in the way that you are searching the inbox other than the frequency that you are doing it.

The only way to "reset" the quota is by waiting for the next day.